# Hugging Face: NameError: name 'sentences' is not defined

Tags: python, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I am following this tutorial here: https://huggingface.co/transformers/training.html - though, I am coming across an error, and I think the tutorial is missing an import, but i do not know which.

These are my current imports:

```
# Transformers installation
! pip install transformers
# To install from source instead of the last release, comment the command above and uncomment the following one.
# ! pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git

! pip install datasets transformers

from transformers import pipeline
```

Current code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset

raw_datasets = load_dataset("imdb")
```

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
```

```
inputs = tokenizer(sentences, padding="max_length", truncation=True)
```

The error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-9-5a234f114e2e> in <module>()
----> 1 inputs = tokenizer(sentences, padding="max_length", truncation=True)

NameError: name 'sentences' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that you do not have a variable called `sentences` in the scope. I believe the tutorial presumes you already have a list of sentences and are tokenizing it.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__) The first argument can be either a string or list of string or list of list of strings.

```
__call__(text: Union[str, List[str], List[List[str]]],...)
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks for that - I will take a look at it. Also, is there a way to do something like this using my own dataset? Here: https://huggingface.co/nlptown/bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment?text=I+like+you.+I+love+you

Comment: You can pass anything that you have parsed as one of the types I described so yes, of course. You just need to write a little code to convert it to one of these types

Comment: Okay, thanks. Therefore, is it possible to use my dataset to classify the sentiment of a sentence being either "happy", "sad" or "angry?"

Answer (score 2):

This error is because you have not declared sentences. Now you need to
access raw data using:

```
k = raw_datasets['train']
sentences = k['text']
```

Answer (score 1):

create a variable

```
sentences = ["Hello I'm a single sentence",
             "And another sentence",
             "And the very very last one"]
```

**"As we saw in [Preprocessing data](https://huggingface.co/transformers/preprocessing.html), we can prepare the text inputs for the model with the following command (this is an example, not a command you can execute)"**

Comment: Hello - thanks for the reply. What exactly are these sentences used for?

Comment: Hiya, these sentences are used on a different tutorial from the website youre using. In the quote above, i got it from the tutorial youre currently following.
So just showing you what you should add(an example) to get rid of the error